# Can I restrict user to write only site link in zend form text field

Tags: zend-framework

//i want user can only write the links instead other text

```
$url = $this->createElement('textarea','url');
    $url->setLabel('Url: ');
    $url->setRequired(true);
    $url->setAttrib('cols',40);
    $url->setAttrib('rows',4);
    $this->addElement($url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to only validate one link, you can add a URL validator to your field. Something like below.

```
$url = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('url');
$url->setOptions(
    array(
        'label'      => 'Url: ',
        'validators' => array(
                            'NotEmpty',
                            array(
                                'Callback',
                                true,
                                array(
                                    'callback' => function($value) {
                                        return Zend_Uri::check($value);
                                    }
                                ),
                                'messages' => array(
                                    Zend_Validate_Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'Please enter a valid URL',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom validator.
There are many examples in the web like [here](http://www.techchorus.net/validate-uri-form-fields-zend-framework-custom-validator) or [here](http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-components-13/core-infrastructure-19/how-do-i-validate-url-1269.html)  or [here](http://wiip.fr/content/zend-framework-validateur-pour-une-url) (in french) ...

After coding `Your_Validate_Uri` class you can do this:

```
$url->addValidator(new Your_Validate_Uri());
```